# How to create a realistic tooth enamel material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I tried to mix the *Glossy* and *Translucent* shaders to create the enamel material, but the effect wasn't good. Have you got any ideas how to set up the nodes to make it look realistic?

[image]

Comment: Good results can be done only with tooth geometries that consist of 2 surfaces: dentin (refraction 1,45) and enamel (refraction 1.7). The tooth is an anisotropic volume with numerous layers non of which is actualy solid. Can you give us some dental scan or something? I can do some tests in the evening -> mix of glossy, sss, transparent and volume absorption should yield what you want

Comment: @Gonzou, nice teeth. where do you go to the dentist? :D

Comment: Thanks Vince. Nice to hear you like it :). The secret is I just brush my teeth regulary ;).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*(this is a converted comment)*

Good results can be done with tooth geometries that consist of 2 surfaces: dentin (refraction 1,45) and enamel (refraction 1.7).

The tooth is an anisotropic volume with numerous layers non of which is actualy solid.

Front-lit:

[image]

Back-lit:

[image]

Can you give us some dental scan or something? That way I can do some tests in the evening.

It should be mix of sss and transparent for the enamel with glossy on surface and yellow tinted volume absorption for dentin.

This should yield what you want. Adding the refraction and anisotropic element should also help but maybe that will be just an overkill..

Comment: Very interesting! How the geometry have to look like? A tooth and another one inside it right?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Jerryno! I'll give it a try.